# Permission denied but publickey added on server?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, terminal

In ~/.ssh/authorized_keys I have added a public-key of a user that would like to connect to the server.

When that user tries to connect he gets a Permission denied (publickey) error. Error log:

```
input_userauth_request: invalid user USERNAME [preauth]
```

In my config (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) file I have:

```
AllowUsers USERNAME
```

In my config (/~.ssh/config), I have:

```
Host hostname
  User root
  User USERNAME
  HostName IP address
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  PubKeyAuthentication yes
```

Why can't he login to the server?

Answer (score 0):

> input_userauth_request: invalid user USERNAME [preauth]

Means that the user does not exist on the server. Is it a local user or a user from some LDAP/IdM? If it should be local, and is not in `/etc/passwd`, you should add it first (for example using `useradd`).

> ```
> User root
> User USERNAME
> ```

This is also wrong. In this case, `root` user will be used, not your `USERNAME`.